# Is it possible to use Caribou on the login screen instead of onboard?

Tags: keyboard, screen, accessibility, unity-greeter

When using GNOME Shell it comes with Caribou, an on screen keyboard that looks really nice (on par with screen keyboards found on iOS and Android). I see that Unity Greeter is configured to use onboard as the default on screen keyboard for those with touch screen devices.

Is it possible to substitute onboard with Caribou through configuration?

Answer (score 5):

The onscreen keyboard is launched by the [Unity Greeter](https://launchpad.net/unity-greeter). The version that is in Ubuntu 11.10 is hard-coded to use onboard, but there is no reason why it shouldn't be able to use either.  Please [file a bug](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug) / write a patch to unity-greeter.